# Using terraform to fetch entity name under alias

Tags: hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-vault

I am trying to fetch all the entity names using data source vault_identity_entity, however unable to fetch the name of entity located under aliases.

Sample code:
'''

```
data “vault_identity_group” “group” {
group_name = “vaultadmin”
}
data “vault_identity_entity” “entity” {
for_each = toset(data.vault_identity_group.group.member_entity_ids)
entity_id = each.value
}
data “null_data_source” “values” {
for_each = data.vault_identity_entity.entity
inputs = {
ssh_user_details = lookup(jsondecode(data.vault_identity_entity.entity[each.key].data_json),“name”,{})
}
}

"data_json": "{\"aliases\":[{\"canonical_id\":\"37b4c764-a4ec-dcb7-c3c7-31cf9c51e456\",\"creation_time\":\"2022-07-20T08:53:36.553988277Z\",\"custom_metadata\":null,\"id\":\"59fb8a9c-1c0c-0591-0f6e-1a153233e456\",\"last_update_time\":\"2022-07-20T08:53:36.553988277Z\",\"local\":false,\"merged_from_canonical_ids\":null,\"metadata\":null,\"mount_accessor\":\"auth_approle_12d1d8af\",\"mount_path\":\"auth/approle/\",\"mount_type\":\"approle\",\"name\":\"name.user@test.com\"}],\"creation_time\":\"2022-07-20T08:53:36.553982983Z\",\"direct_group_ids\":[\"e456cb46-2b51-737c-3277-64082352f47e\"],\"disabled\":false,\"group_ids\":[\"e456cb46-2b51-737c-3277-64082352f47e\"],\"id\":\"37b4c764-a4ec-dcb7-c3c7-31cf9c51e456\",\"inherited_group_ids\":[],\"last_update_time\":\"2022-07-20T08:53:36.553982983Z\",\"merged_entity_ids\":null,\"metadata\":null,\"name\":\"entity_ec5c123\",\"namespace_id\":\"root\",\"policies\":[]}",
```

Above scripts returns entity id entity_ec5c123. Any suggestions to retrieve the name field under aliases, which has users email id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
data “vault_identity_group” “group” {
  group_name = “vaultadmin”
}

data “vault_identity_entity” “entity” {
  for_each = toset(data.vault_identity_group.group.member_entity_ids)
  entity_id = each.value
}

locals {
  mount_accessor      = "auth_approle_12d1d8af"
  # mount_path        = "auth/approle/"
  aliases             = {for k,v in data.vault_identity_entity.entity : k => jsondecode(v.data_json, "aliases") }
}

data “null_data_source” “values” {
  for_each = data.vault_identity_entity.entity
  inputs = {
    ssh_user_details = lookup({for alias in lookup(local.aliases, each.key, "ent_missing") : alias.mount_accessor => alias.name}, local.mount_accessor, "ent_no_alias_on_auth_method")
  }
}
```

Basically you want to do a couple lookups here, you can simplify this if you can guarantee that each entity will only have a single alias, but otherwise you should probably be looking up the alias for a specific `mount_accessor` and discarding the other entries.

Haven't really done a bunch of testing with this code, but you should be able to run `terraform console` after doing an init on your workspace and figure out what the data structs look like if you have issues.